# Method undefined for type ImageView

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an ImageView and to set its position without XML.

I've the following code:

```
public class myClass {
    Activity act;
    public myClass(Activity act) {
        this.act = act;
    }

    public void setImage(){
        ImageView img = new ImageView(act);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimg);
        float xpos = 100;
        img.setX(xpos);
    }

}
```

I get the error:

> "The method setX(float) is undefined for the type ImageView"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is only available since API level 11:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setX(float)

Are you sure your coding for this API level?

Comment: Oh well, I'm developing for level 8...
Thank you & Sorry for the noise

Answer (score 0):

As ImageView extends View which offers the public Method setX this should work, unless maybe you imported the wrong ImageView. Check your import statement.

Comment: Not downvoting. `setX` method is not available in the Android version below 3.0 (API Level 11). See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setX%28float%29